# Beginner package developer fails to knitr its first README.Rmd due to "could not find function"

Tags: r, package

I have a package for some tasks,
containing some files such as like, `foo.R` and `README.Rmd`.

Now `foo.R` has a simple function, like:

```r
#' Hello, world!
#'
#' @export
hello <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```

And in `README.Rmd` , I describe how `foo.R` works, like:

```r
library(test)  # suppose the package name is `test`
hello()
```

Suppose other part typically required in `README.Rmd` (e.g. yaml) is
written as default.
And I excute (in R Studio) Ctrl + Shift + D (`devtools::document()`) and Ctrl + Shift + B,
Then I knitr it (Ctrl + Shift + K), and get error with message:

```
Error in hello() : could not find function "hello"
```

I've tried many other way (like actually uploading it to github and installing it), but it doesn't help.
Please tell me what is wrong!

Comment: It's unlikely we can help you without seeing the actual package.  Have you got it on Github?  The kinds of things that could have gone wrong:  the package install could have failed.  It could have been installed with a different name.  It could have been installed to a different library.  You could have another package named `test` that `knitr` finds ahead of yours.  Etc.

Comment: do `test::hello()` or `test:::hello()` work?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! The problem was resolved suddenly. But it seems that the cause of the problem was a little different in the case study and the actual package. The cause of the error in the test package was that it was not built properly. But in the actual package, the cause was that `devtools::install_github()` was executed in the README.Rmd. In both cases, after a proper build was done, knitr was able to do it.